# Customise column names in df.pivot Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I would like to pivot a dataframe `df` as below, with `Id` as index, `Value` as values, and customised columns `[x0, x1, x2]`.

`df`

```
            Id  Date                 Value
    9129    10  2021-01-01 00:00:00  10
    9130    10  2021-01-01 00:01:00  15
    9131    10  2021-01-01 00:02:00  20
    1972    13  2021-01-01 00:00:00  125.0
    1973    13  2021-01-01 00:01:00  225.0
    1974    13  2021-01-01 00:02:00  325.0
    1134    15  2021-01-01 00:00:00  100000
    1135    15  2021-01-01 00:01:00  200000
    1136    15  2021-01-01 00:02:00  300000
```

Expected output:

```
      x0     x1     x2            
10    10     15     20    
13    125    225    325   
15    100000 200000 300000
```

I tried:

```
df.pivot(index = 'Id', columns = ['x0','x1','x2'],  values = 'Value')
```

and it caught error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-02a6ff0e046a> in <module>


----> 3 df.pivot(index = 'Id', columns = ['x0','x1','x2'],  values = 'Value')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
   6665         from pandas.core.reshape.pivot import pivot
   6666 
-> 6667         return pivot(self, index=index, columns=columns, values=values)
   6668 
   6669     _shared_docs[

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    463             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    464 
--> 465         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    466         index.extend(data_columns)
    467         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    463             index = [data[idx] for idx in index]
    464 
--> 465         data_columns = [data[col] for col in columns]
    466         index.extend(data_columns)
    467         index = MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2897             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2898                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2899             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2900             if is_integer(indexer):
   2901                 indexer = [indexer]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2889                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2890             except KeyError as err:
-> 2891                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2892 
   2893         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'x0'
```

How do you customise the column names? How to do it for 50 columns, ie., from `x0` to `x49`?

Comment: You're either going to have to change the `Date` column before pivoting (or an in-line Series with `pivot_table`) or rename just the columns after pivoting. But there is no renaming allowed in the pandas pivot function itself. Something like `df.pivot(index='Id', columns='Date',  values='Value').set_axis(np.arange(3), axis=1).add_prefix('x')` could work.

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker Is it possible to standardise the columns? I will have different columns names(`Date`) for different `Id`.

Comment: Assuming by "standardise" you mean that you want the first value per id to be in the first column, second value per id to be in the second column etc, then [Shubham Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12833166/shubham-sharma)'s [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998796/15497888) accomplishes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a sequential counter using `groupby` + `cumcount`, then use it as columns in `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table('Value', 'Id', df.groupby('Id').cumcount()).add_prefix('x')
```

---

```
          x0        x1        x2
Id                              
10      10.0      15.0      20.0
13     125.0     225.0     325.0
15  100000.0  200000.0  300000.0
```

Comment: Clever approach. Assumes dates are in the same order within every group though (which is easily remedied just may be worth mentioning that this pivot logic doesn't actually consider the Date column at all) although given the request to "standardise the columns" that may be exactly what is expected.

Comment: Brilliant solution, thanks Shubham. Is `pivot_table` more favourable than `pivot`?

Comment: `pivot` and `pivot_table` are two separate things, you would use `pivot_table` if you want to perform aggregation along with reshaping on the other-hand `pivot` does not support aggregation of data.